# Reactjs assigning key prop to array rendered components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am rendering some components using array map function, and I'm getting "Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop." warning. I know that I do have to assign key props to the array rendered components.

My question is, do I have to just assign key to the most outer component (this case View) that is inside the map function, or do I have to assign key to every element inside the outer most component view?

If latter is the case, then assigning key to every component is a little inefficient I think? Is there any way to solve this problem? Thank you

```
this.state.Store.City.map((item) => {
        return <View>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.onQueryInputChange(item)}>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, paddingVertical: 10 }}>
              {item.fullName}
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      })
```

Comment: The outer most element needs key. In your case add key prop to View. and not required for other elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have an id in `item`, you can use the item array index if the list will not be reordered or reorganized :

```
this.state.Store.City.map((item, index) => {
   return (
     <View key={index}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.onQueryInputChange(item)}>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, paddingVertical: 10 }}>
          {item.fullName}
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
     </View>
   );
})
```

Only the outermost component needs a key to keep track of each item.

Answer (score 1):

You should assign a key to the most outter component (here it would be `View` component) 
here is the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#extracting-components-with-keys)

if item has an `ìd` property you could write

```
this.state.Store.City.map((item) => {
   return (
     <View key={item.id}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.onQueryInputChange(item)}>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, paddingVertical: 10 }}>
          {item.fullName}
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
     </View>
   );
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I got it solved really appreciate it!